# Sending HTTP Form Encoded Request C#

Tags: c#

I've set up a Jetty Server (written in Java) which handles HTTP requests. The server works fine, and when I use the Jetty HTTP client, I have no problems.

I'm now trying to send my server requests from C#. Here is my code -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Requests
{
public static void Main ()
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task RunAsync ()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "create");

        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Topics001", "Batman"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Account", "5"));

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> s in postData)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
}
```

I can confirm from my server that it's receiving the request to the correct address, but inexplicably, the request content is null. It's never getting the content I'm trying to send over.

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`? It takes care of much of the HTTP-creation code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Requests
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var postData = new NameValueCollection()
                {
                    {"Topics001", "Batman"},
                    {"Account", "5"}
                };

                var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
                var response = await client.UploadValuesTaskAsync(uri, postData);

                var result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to C#. Trying this on Visual Studio raises the compile error - "Namespace 'UI' does not exist in 'System.Web'. Have you forgotten to add a reference?" What might that mean?

Comment: Also, how would I run this? Call Page_Load from another method with a Main class? What parameters would I pass in?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did this in a web project, that's why it's being called from page load. You don't need the page load and can just copy the method and call it from your main

Comment: I have edited the code to more closely match your class / method naming

Comment: Bizarrely, this approach also failed until I changed the POST request to a PUT request. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Without looking at the receiving service, I can't know for sure. Are you certain that it expects and only accepts POSTs? Or maybe the service actually expects GETs. When you call it in the "good" way, fire up Fiddler and look at how the requests are being sent